# removing object from array with filters doesnt work in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove an object from an array but it I dont know what I am doing wrong.

I have this array declared:

```js
listA: [
       { title: 'Food', value: 'Patato' },
       { title: 'Drink', value: 'Cola' },
       { title: 'Desert', value: 'Cheesecake' },
       ],
```

I am trying to remove the object where its value is 'Cola', what I have tried is this:

```
  this.listA.filter(x => x.value !== 'Cola');
```

And it returns me the same list

I want to return this:

```
 listA: [
   { title: 'Food', value: 'Patato' },
   { title: 'Desert', value: 'Cheesecake' },
   ],
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be filtering just fine, I think the issue here is that `filter` does not modify the original array, it returns a new array with the filtered results. If you want it to overwrite the original array, you'll need to say `this.listA = this.listA.filter(...)`

Comment: Thank you, it works!!

Answer (score 1):

```
const listA = [
  { title: "Food", value: "Patato" },
  { title: "Drink", value: "Cola" },
  { title: "Desert", value: "Cheesecake" },
];

const result = listA.filter((obj) => obj.value !== 'Cola');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to do something like

```js
this.listA = this.listA.filter(x => x.value !== 'Cola')
```

The filter method is immutable hence the original array isn't changed

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70688107/6316468, here is what `filter` does under the hood (the original array `this` remains untouched):

```js
var xs = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var ys = filter.call(
  xs, x => x % 2
);
console.log(
  "xs = [", xs.join(), "]"
);
console.log(
  "ys = [", ys.join(), "]"
);

function filter(predicate) {
  var xs = []; // new array
  for (let x in this) {
    if (predicate(x)) {
      xs.push(x);
    }
  }
  return xs;
}
```